# Access WebRole data from .aspx page

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am working on TCP/IP in Windows Azure and am successfully able to develop a TCP client to send and web-role to receive the TCP data.

I want to display this received data in a .aspx page. How should I access the webrole data from .aspx page?

Regards,
Anil

Comment: What are you asking? You've written that you have success in sending/receiving data with webrole instance and ask how to do it in next question. Try to understand what you want

Comment: As @DenisAgarev said: What are you asking? How are you receiving TCP data? Via aspx page? Via web services endpoint?

Maybe the issue is that you're not clear on what a Web Role is, since you want to know how to access 'Web Role data.' A Web Role is Windows Server 2008 running IIS, where your Web Application is running, and you have one more more *instances* of that Web Role running at any given time.

What would you do if this was your own Windows Server? Where would your data be? How would you return it?

Comment: @DavidMakogon,I am able to receive TCP data from a TCP endpoint, and am able to see the received data in webrole.cs file using debug mode. What I am asking for is how to display the received data in a UI.aspx page.

Comment: @DenisAgarev I am able to receive TCP data from a TCP endpoint, and am able to see the received data in webrole.cs file using debug mode. What I am asking for is how to display the received data in a UI.aspx page

Comment: Well first of all if you are not familiar with asp.net, i recommend you to choose MVC3/4 web site instead of web forms or choose razor view engine if you work with it. Then just open http://www.asp.net/ and look for common asp.net samples which this site is full of (also with azure).

Comment: @DenisAgarev Hi, I looked into MVC architecture as you suggested and understood the flow. My question is how can i fetch the data into Controller from Webrole.cs file. I am using the following code to receive the TCP data:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh285885

Answer (score 0):

Having read the long comment stream, I think I get the essence of this scenario and question. It appears that there's some tcp-listener code being launched from within webrole.cs, not within the asp.net app code.

Here's the thing: A Web Role is Windows Server 2008 with IIS, along with some Windows Azure code for handling bootstrap and shutdown tasks. The `webrole.cs` file you speak of is the bootstrap/shutdown code entry point, with methods such as `OnStart()`, `Run()`, `OnStop()`, and `Stopping()`. This code is run in a separate AppDomain than your web app.

If you're launching a ServiceHost (or some other port listener) from webrole.cs, that's fine, but you'd need to then store content somewhere temporarily after it's uploaded, then make it available for your web app later. You could choose *durable* storage such as SQL Azure or Azure Storage (blobs or tables), or *volatile* storage (e.g. a local disk). You could then use some type of communication scheme to notify your web app that it has new data display, possibly by placing a message on an Azure queue, or having your web app just query a table for data each time a user requests it.